# Add onclick event on various elements on the basic of CSS class

Tags: javascript, onclick, prototypejs, dom-events

I have various elements on a single page. They share a single class.
 I want to add a onclick event on all those elements using prototype.

For id I can do something like this:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load',
   function() {
$('id_of_the_element').addEventListener('onclick',any_function,true);
  }
);
```

This is good if we have id of the element. I want to do the same using CSS class, cause all the element share same class.

Update:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
   $$('.message').invoke('observe', 'click', hide_all_messages)
});

function hide_all_messages()
{
$$('.message').hide();
}
```

This is not working.

error:

> hide is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$$('.myClass').each(
  function(element){
    Event.observe("click",element,any_function);
}
);
```

you got it !

Comment: $$(".message").invoke("hide")

Answer (score 1):

a more succinct solution would be to use [invoke](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/invoke):

```
$$('.elements').invoke('observe', 'click', yourfunction)
```

You can set this to run when the dom is ready by placing it within this code:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('.elements').invoke('observe', 'click', yourfunction)
});
```

**EDIT** - this will fix your other issue:

```
function hide_all_messages(){
    $$('.message').invoke("hide");
}
```